# replication of minimal sufficient statistic

Tags: distributions, sufficient-statistics, complete-statistics

Suppose we have a minimal sufficient statistic for observations $X_1, ...,X_n$ that are i.i.d from distribution $f(X|\theta)$, namely $T(X) = (T_1,...,T_k)$ which is a $k$ dimensional statistics. Now we create a new statistics such as follows :
$T^\prime(X) = T(X).T(X).T(X) = (T_1,...,T_k,T_1,...,T_k,T_1,...,T_k)$
where we have concatenated initial minimal S.S.

Is new created statistics minimal and sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed $T^\prime$ is also sufficient and minimal since it can be written as a function of $T$, hence of any other sufficient statistic.